# How to hide list items until search input receives text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search

I'm new to react and am working on a search feature, I have some dummy data stored in an object, I'm mapping over it and displaying it on the page. I've written the search functionality to search the list which is working great. This may be a stupid question, but I don't want the list items to be displayed on the page until text is entered into the input field, in my head I'm thinking a simple if statement would do, but I'm having a little trouble. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
     const isSearched = searchTerm => item => 
     item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());

     const list = [
     {
        title: 'react',
        url: 'https://reactjs.org',
        author: 'Jordan Walke',
        num_comments: 3,
        points: 4,
        objectID: 0
      },

      {
        title: 'redux',
        url: 'https://redux.js.org',
        author: 'Dan Abramov',
        num_comments: 5,
        points: 6,
        objectID: 1
      },
     ];

     class App extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
         super(props);

        this.state = {
          list: list,
          searchTerm: '',
       };

      this.onSearchChange = this.onSearchChange.bind(this);
    }

      onSearchChange(event) {
      this.setState({ searchTerm: event.target.value });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
        <form>
        <input 
          type="text"
          onChange={this.onSearchChange}
        />
      </form>
      {this.state.list.filter(isSearched(this.state.searchTerm)).map(item 
       => 
      <div key={item.objectID}>
        <span>
          <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
        </span>
        <span>{item.author}</span>
        <span>{item.num_comments}</span>
        <span>{item.points}</span>
          </div>
          )}
       </div>
      );
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be pretty simple. Basically in the render function you need to check in if your `searchTerm` is not `''` then render. it would look like this:

```
{
  this.state.searchTerm !== '' &&
  this.state.list.filter(isSearched(this.state.searchTerm)).map(item =>
    <div key={item.objectID}>
        <span>
            <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
            </span>
           <span>{item.author}</span>
        <span>{item.num_comments}</span>
        <span>{item.points}</span>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: @Mike0809, you're welcome. BTW if you want to check out Alexandre's answer that uses Object Destructuring with `this.state`. Makes things cleaner and less typing.

Comment: I happened to see your response on my screen first, but I tried his as well and it definitely made things cleaner and less typing, thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your filter function in a conditional rendering statement.

```
const { searchTerm, list } = this.state;
{searchTerm !== " " && (
 list.filter(searchTerm).map(item =>
  <div key={item.objectID}>
    <span>
      <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
    </span>
    <span>{item.author}</span>
    <span>{item.num_comments}</span>
    <span>{item.points}</span>
  </div>
 )
)};
```

That way your items are only rendered when searchTerm resolves to true.

> [...] in JavaScript, true && expression always evaluates to
>   expression, and false && expression always evaluates to false.

See [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) in the React's doc